# Using Silverlight 3 to make a WPF Application cross platform (Windows + OS X)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, silverlight, macos

Im writing a Twitter Client in C#/WPF/WCF.

I(Windows) showed some of my friends(OS X) and they would also like to use it.

Would it be worthwhile to convert the application into Silverlight 3 so that they would be able to run/install it on OS X?

Will the full features of Silverlight 3 be supported on OS X (like the install feature), like Silverlight 2 is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/mtaulty/Silverlight-3-Running-Out-Of-Browser-Apps-on-the-Macintosh/) (Mike Taulty on Channel 9, with a screencast showing it working) answers out-of-browser/install in OS X; I'm given to understand that the local install works slightly *differently* (to cater for OS differences), but works.

So: would your friends prefer Silverlight? Or would they happily run [VMware Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/)? (not sure how well that would cope with an intensive WPF app, though).

If your xaml isn't hugely complex, I'd consider SL3 - but going from WPF to Silverlight is trickier than the other way around - there are, understandably, big gaps.

Comment: I dont think they would run VWware Fusion, but they do run Crossover so they can use Office 2007